# What happens if I change my mind on a vote to close/reopen?

Tags: support, review, close-reasons, closed-questions, re-open

In reviewing questions in regard to closure or reopening, I voted to reopen a question (which had been closed for reasons other than duplication), because it seemed a reasonable question. Later, I realized that the question was a duplicate of an earlier question (which was open and upvoted and had received an upvoted and accepted answer). So I voted to close the later-posted question on that ground. Do my two votes stand, and so cancel each other? Or does my later vote supersede the earlier one?

(As it happened, more votes to close on the ground of duplication were received, and the question was closed for that reason.)

Comment: I might not be getting the right picture, but if you were casting a reopen vote on the Question, it must have been closed at that time.  If you later cast a close-as-duplicate on the same Question, it must have become reopened in the meantime.  Is that the way it was?  The two votes both "stand" (they did not cancel each other per se).

Comment: To address the question posed in the title, it is possible to *cancel* a vote to close, a feature that was implemented [back in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) long after it was requested.  (I had the occasion to do this today.)  The situation with reopen votes is not symmetric, and once you cancel a close vote (perhaps to change "reasons"), you are not allowed to case a second close vote on the same Question.